Error: Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date in angular
html:
<div class="form-group">
<nz-date-picker
  class="mt-2"
  formControlName="obsolete_date"
  [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate"
  *ngIf="aboutForm.value.types.obsolete"
  [nzFormat]="'dd-MM-yyyy'">
</nz-date-picker>
</div>

ts:
disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean => {
  const current_date = new Date();
  const selected_date = new Date(current);

  // Calculate yesterday's date
  const yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);

  // Disable if selected date is before yesterday
  return selected_date < yesterday;
};

initializeAboutForm(): void {

  this.aboutForm = this.formBuilder.group({

    obsolete_date: new FormControl(''),

  });

}

setAboutFormData(): void {
  // Patch the form with values from the loaded product

  const loadedObsoleteDate = this.loadedProduct?.obsolete_date;
  console.log('Loaded obsolete date:', loadedObsoleteDate); // Debugging statement result: 19-07-2024 DD-MM-YYYY

  this.aboutForm.patchValue({
    obsolete_date: (loadedObsoleteDate) ? loadedObsoleteDate : '',
  });


}


I got errors while click the nz-date picker how to resolve this issues?

I fixed my issues:
  convertToDate(dateString: string): Date {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('-').map(part => parseInt(part, 10));
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
  }


setAboutFormData(): void {
  // Patch the form with values from the loaded product

  const loadedObsoleteDate = this.loadedProduct?.obsolete_date;
  console.log('Loaded obsolete date:', loadedObsoleteDate); // Debugging statement result: 19-07-2024 DD-MM-YYYY

  this.aboutForm.patchValue({
    obsolete_date: (loadedObsoleteDate) ? this.convertToDate(loadedObsoleteDate) : '',
  });


}

